# client and server time sync with new Date()

Tags: utc, ntp

I am trying to sync time between client and the server as accurate as possible.

I've read through lots of articles and most of them recommend us to use NTP time sync, or stream-based protocols such as TCP.

Both of them requires client first to ask the server time, and sync the time using the round trip time.

But I also came to know that, browser(client) and node(server) outputs the same thing when we use `new Date` with the same timezone(UTC).

so why do we need to sync the time between client and the server?

wouldn't it be better to use UTC time zone respectively?

what is the advantage of using NTP based time sync over using `new Date()` with the same timezone(UTC) on different environments?

Comment: Different computers may have differing clocks, user's computers may have vastly differing clocks, bad actor users may change their clocks on purpose to introduce bugs or cheat etc. Using a common trusted source fixes this, though people can still work around it sometimes, you should always assume every client can't be trusted!

Comment: @koo I think you're missing the point: you can never trust remote clients (and timezones are irrelevant: always use only UTC)

Comment: I can change my phone's clock to be 9:00 am Nov 1st 1940 right now :)

Comment: How would the device know though? There is no way for a device to pluck out the correct time out of thin air. It has to be told the time. Normally this happens at the factory, but it doesn't necessarily stay accurate forever. Even digital watches break. (And the point about people intentionally changing the device clock time is well made, too. If a licence lasts till 2021, and a user sets theri computer to be permanently in 2020 to avoid the licence, you'd want to know.)

Answer (score 1):

Unless a computer uses NTP, it cannot be assumed that it knows the exact time.  Just like analog clocks, especially with older computers, the clock could tick faster or slower, getting progressively more inaccurate. Or a battery might fail, resulting in the computer losing the time information, and resetting to a default; and NTP is the mechanism by which the computer can ask an authoritative source to make sure its clock is correct. People used church bells to make sure their grandfather clocks were running on time, then they'd use the TV news; now NTP serves that purpose.

On a server, you can make sure an NTP client is running, which ensures the server clock is correct (or rather, synchronised with the upstream NTP server, which would hopefully be synced with the trusted stratum-0 devices, such as atomic clocks or GPS systems).

Since you have no control over a client computer, it could be in January 1970, for all you know, and asking the server you trust is the safest course.

Comment: My computers all use NTP and they sometimes get the wrong time because the hardware clock in one of my domain-controllers will be off somewhat. So using NTP does not imply anything about accuracy.

Comment: Fair. But it does guarantee it is the same as the NTP server. If you're using your own NTP server instead of the ones trusted worldwide, that's on you :)